# Creating a WAV file with an arbitrary bits per sample value?

Tags: vb.net, audio, text-to-speech, wav, speech-synthesis

Do *WAV* files allow any arbitrary number of `bitsPerSample`?

I have failed to get it to work with anything less than 8. I am not sure how to define the `blockAlign` for one thing.

```
Dim ss As New Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
Dim info As New Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo(AudioFormat.EncodingFormat.Pcm, 5000, 4, 1, 2500, 1, Nothing) ' FAILS
ss.SetOutputToWaveFile("TEST4bit.wav", info)
ss.Speak("I am 4 bit.")
My.Computer.Audio.Play("TEST4bit.wav")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK **no**, 4-bit PCM format is *undefined*, it wouldn't make much sense to have 16 volume levels of audio; quality would be horrible.

While technically possible, I know no decent software (e.g. Wavelab) that supports it, your very own player could though.

Formula: `blockAlign = channels * (bitsPerSample / 8)`

So for a mono 4-bit it would be : `blockAlign = 1 * ((double)4 / 8) = 0.5`

Note the usage of `double` being necessary to not end up with `0`.

But if you look at the block align definition below, it really does not make much sense to have an alignment of `0.5` bytes, one would have to work at the bit-level (painful and useless because at this quality, non-compressed PCM would just sound horrible):

*wBlockAlign*

*The block alignment (in bytes) of the waveform data. Playback
software needs to process a multiple of wBlockAlign bytes of data at
a time, so the value of wBlockAlign can be used for buffer
alignment.*

**Reference:**

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Docs/riffmci.pdf page 59

**Workaround:**

If you really need 4-bit, switch to ADPCM format.

Comment: Thanks. It seems, the WAV files define `ADPCM` as a valid option, however .NET's `AudioFormat.EncodingFormat` enumeration only has `Pcm`, `ALaw` and `ULaw`. Does it mean I cannot generate ADPCM WAV files from .NET?

Comment: I don't think you can, but take a look at this library : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917346/algorithm-for-converting-pcm-to-ima-adpcm

Comment: So, the `bitsPerSample` has to be a multiple of 8?

Comment: It is commonly a multiple of 8, could be anything else, though (but likely not to be supported unless a specific software is used).

Comment: @MCU No it can be any number of bits.  wBlockAlign  would be 1, not 0.5.  So it would be stored like 8-bit audio, just without using the least significant bits of each byte.

Comment: Yes you're right it's an old answer, should be (4+7)/8=1